# Check if a value is present in a property of any object in a list of objects

Tags: angular, optimization

I have a list of the following sort:

```
[
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.0"
    },
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.1"
    },
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.2"
    },
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.3"
    },
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.4"
    }
]
```

I want to check if **"FIX.4.3"** is present in the **"_name"** property of any of these objects or not.
I can't change the format of the list (No matter how much I want to) because I fetch it from somewhere else.
I know I can loop through the objects, but I'm looking for a better way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Example:

```js
const data = [
        {
            "_name": "FIX.4.0"
        },
        {
            "_name": "FIX.4.1"
        },
        {
            "_name": "FIX.4.2"
        },
        {
            "_name": "FIX.4.3"
        },
        {
            "_name": "FIX.4.4"
        }
    ];
    
    // FIX.4.4 is there
    console.log(data.some(x => x._name === "FIX.4.4"));
    
    // FIX.NOT.THERE is, well, not
    console.log(data.some(x => x._name === "FIX.NOT.THERE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** :

```
checkValue(value){
    if(this.array.find(function(obj) { return obj._name === value; }))
      return true
    else
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as sloth, but using find like fateme fazli

Exemple

```js
const data = [
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.0"
    },
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.1"
    },
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.2"
    },
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.3"
    },
    {
        "_name": "FIX.4.4"
    }
];

const result = (data.find(x => x._name === "FIX.4.3") === undefined) ? false : true;

console.log(result);
```